# Result Maps collection does not contain value error while ResultMap.xml to @Mapper class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to bind the result of the query (inside @Mapper class and using @Select annotation for the query) to a Mapper.xml as I have a pretty complex POJO to map to.

Here is my code:

**MapMapper.class :**

```
@Mapper
public interface MapMapper {

    @Select("select seat_id,row_pos,column_pos,is_assigned,team_id,map_id from t002_seat_mst where map_id=#{mapId}")
    @ResultMap("SeatsResultMap")
    MapDTO fetchMapSeatsByIdWhenNoTeam(int mapId);

}
```

**SeatsMapper.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.seat.arrangement.dao.mapper.MapMapper">
    <resultMap id="SeatsResultMap" type="com.seat.arrangement.model.MapDTO">
        <result column="map_id" jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="mapId" />
        <collection property="seats" ofType="com.seat.arrangement.model.SeatDTO">
            <result property="seatId" column="seat_id" />
            <result property="rowNumber" column="row_pos" />
            <result property="columnNumber" column="column_pos" />
            <result property="isAssigned" column="is_assigned" />
            <result property="team.teamId" column="team_id" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

**Error log :**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection does not contain value for com.seat.arrangement.dao.mapper.MapMapper.SeatsResultMap
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:964) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getResultMap(Configuration.java:674) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.getStatementResultMaps(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:339) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.addMappedStatement(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:285) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parseStatement(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:358) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MethodResolver.resolve(MethodResolver.java:33) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.lambda$buildAllStatements$3(Configuration.java:824) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:544) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.buildAllStatements(Configuration.java:823) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.hasStatement(Configuration.java:792) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.hasStatement(Configuration.java:787) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.resolveMappedStatement(MapperMethod.java:257) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:227) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedMapperMethod$0(MapperProxy.java:98) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:97) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:92) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.fetchAllTeams(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.seat.arrangement.dao.impl.FetchMapsDaoImpl.fetchAllTeams(FetchMapsDaoImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.seat.arrangement.service.impl.FetchMapServiceImpl.fetchAllTeams(FetchMapServiceImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.seat.arrangement.rest.SeatingArrangementController.fetchAllTeams(SeatingArrangementController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

I do have a `mybatis-config.xml` file inside `resources/config/mybatis-config.xml`

**mybatis-config.xml :**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN'
        'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd'>
<!--<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Confi 3.0//EN"
        "config//mybatis-3-config.dtd">-->
<configuration>

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource='config/SeatsMapper.xml'/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Since I am provide jdbc properties from the `application.properties` file, I have only used `<mappers></mappers>` in `mybatis-config.xml`. Is it wrong?

**Here is my application.properties file :**

```
server.port=7777

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

mybatis.config=classpath:config//mybatis-config.xml
```

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the last line in the application.properties : `mybatis.config=classpath:config//mybatis-config.xml` -> `mybatis.config-location=classpath:/config/mybatis-config.xml`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ave.It worked. small change but very efficient.